# Can we cancel a method invoked using PhoneGap.exe

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to PhoneGap and I am trying to develop a small iPhone application based on PhoneGap. My question is, is there a way to cancel the execution of a method invoked by calling PhoneGap.exec() method. Something like PhoneGap.Cancel() or something..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in exec only, you can send an action to cancel any action that you had previously initiated using exec.